# JS How to get class of elements

Tags: javascript, validation

I am creating a dynamic form and some elements are are required and some are not. 
and i was trying to find out how to get the elements that are so i can check if they have a value in them or not.

```
$('form').submit(function() {     
  $('input').each(function(){ 
    isrequired(this.id)
  });

});


function isrequired(id){ 
  if (id!=''){
      // if (it has the class 'require'){ 
      //    return true
      // }
      // return false 
  }   
}
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
    if (this.value == $(this).attr('title')){ 
     this.value = '';
    }     
  });     
  $('input').each(function(){ 
    required = isrequired(this.id)
    if (required == true){
      alert(this.id + ' ' + required)
    } 
  });
});

function isrequired(id){ 
  if (id!=''){
      x = document.getElementById(id)
      if(x.className.indexOf("required") > -1){
        return true
      }else{
        return false
      } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To test if the element whose `id` is "id" has a class "yourclassname", you may use `$('#'+id).hasClass("yourclassname")` :

```
function isrequired(id){ 
   return  $('#'+id).hasClass('require');
}
```

But you're not using the result of isrequired in your first loop so I'm a little doubtful about your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `.hasClass` function

```
function isrequired(id)
{ 
  if ($('#'+id).hasClass(classname))
  {
  }
  else
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: `hasClass` takes the name of the class as parameter, not `'.'+classname`.

Comment: @dystroy oops, I didn't notice I added that. Thanks